# Custom AOSP Keyboard Error: DictionaryProvider ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android-softkeyboard, classnotfoundexception, android-source, android-input-method

I'm trying to build the AOSP keyboard from the 5.0.2 branch after adding some custom code to obtain pressure values for key touches. I'm using `lunch full-eng` to build the source and using `mm` to build LatinIME after I've added my changes.

I'm then pushing LatinIME to /system/apps/ on my Galaxy S3 after removing the previous version. I'm running an unofficial version of CM12 5.0.2 on the device.

The error I get is below which appears to have nothing to do with my code changes but more likely in the way I'm building the app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12198): Process: com.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 12198
E/AndroidRuntime(12198): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.inputmethod.dictionarypack.DictionaryProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.inputmethod.dictionarypack.DictionaryProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/LatinIME.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4969)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4561)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4501)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.inputmethod.dictionarypack.DictionaryProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/LatinIME.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4954)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.inputmethod.dictionarypack.DictionaryProvider
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):        ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I'm new to compiling Android source, so perhaps this is obvious, but should I be building for my specific device instead of using `lunch full-eng`?

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building platforms apps, most of them are pre-optimized. By adding **WITH_DEXPREOPT := false** it will build the apk with a dex file inside.

Verify the LatinIME.apk you are pushing to your device has a classes.dex file in it (unzip -l). If it does not, add the **WITH_DEXPREOPT** to the *Android.mk* file for LatinIME.

Comment: No classes.dex file in the LatinIME.apk, so I'll give this a shot tonight. Looks like it wants a full rebuild with this change and won't let me `mm` the LatinIME module


    `build/core/main.mk:528: WITH_DEXPREOPT has been modified: false 
    build/core/main.mk:528: previous value: true
    build/core/main.mk:528: *** The following variables have been changed: WITH_DEXPREOPT.  Stop.`

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. I ended up having to run `make -j WITH_DEXPREOPT=false`, as I could not get the compiler to stop complaining about the variable being changed as I mentioned before.  While LatinIME is still throwing errors, I believe they are unrelated to this initial issue. The follow-up question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102236/aosp-keyboard-nosuchmethoderror-createemptydictfilenative)