# AOSP Keyboard: NoSuchMethodError - createEmptyDictFileNative

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-source, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to build the AOSP keyboard from the 5.0.2 branch after adding some custom code to obtain pressure values for key touches. I'm using `lunch full-eng` to build the source and using `mm` to build LatinIME after I've added my changes.

I was having trouble with pre-optimization but was helped here on how to solve [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005500/custom-aosp-keyboard-error-dictionaryprovider-classnotfoundexception). I'm now having the following error:

```
E/dalvikvm(  729): ERROR: couldn't find native method
E/dalvikvm(  729): Requested: Lcom/android/inputmethod/latin/BinaryDictionary;.createEmptyDictFileNative:(Ljava/lang/String;J[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Z
W/dalvikvm(  729): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; thrown while initializing Lcom/android/inputmethod/latin/utils/JniUtils;
W/dalvikvm(  729): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; thrown while initializing Lcom/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME;
W/dalvikvm(  729): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME;)
D/AndroidRuntime(  729): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  729): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f1ada0)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  729): Process: com.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 729
E/AndroidRuntime(  729): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/android/inputmethod/latin/BinaryDictionary;.createEmptyDictFileNative(Ljava/lang/String;J[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Z"
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:435)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.utils.JniUtils.<clinit>(JniUtils.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.<clinit>(LatinIME.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2723)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`LatinIME.java` has the following comment regarding this call:

> Loading the native library eagerly to avoid unexpected
>   UnsatisfiedLinkError at the initial
>   JNI call as much as possible.

And `JniUtils.java` makes the call

`System.loadLibrary(JniLibName.JNI_LIB_NAME);`

where `JNI_LIB_NAME` is supposedly defined in `com.android.inputmethod.latin.define.JniLibName`. This is where I believe my issue partially is.

1. `BinaryDictionary.java` does not contain a `createEmptyDictFileNave` method
2. `com.android.inputmethod.latin.define.JniLibName` does not exist in the source code I got from Google's repo.

Like always, any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm very new to Android source building. Thank you.

Regards,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled up [this search](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.0.2_r1/com/android/inputmethod/latin/define/JniLibName.java#JniLibName.0JNI_LIB_NAME)on the package you're using and found that the class and method you're looking for do exist and for some reason you seem not to have it on your local repository.

Have you tried syncing/pulling the Google source code again? You may have `git stash` your changes before you sync (you can see the details of the command and its use [here.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

I'm doing some system app modification/creation as well and all the sources I needed were available when I built using `mm`.

My last suggestion would be to make sure you `make` the `full-eng` platform first once before you try compiling the LatinIME by itself. I had to do that for my app and I believe it will apply to your case too.

Best of luck - hope it turns out well!

Comment: It seems that the problem has been pulling from master. Not sure what happened, but some where along the way it seems as though these classes were removed. I was able to find them much like you did, by Googling them and copy their contents. Better way might be to just rollback to the KitKat release or something. Thanks

Comment: I just checked my local sync of the Google sources and its in there - maybe try switching to the 5.0.2 branch? that's what I pulled.

Answer (score 0):

createEmptyDictFileNative is in [BinaryDictionaryUtils](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/utils/BinaryDictionaryUtils.java#43) and JNI_LIB_NAME is [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java-overridable/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/define/JniLibName.java#24).

You might have an outdated version of libjni_latinime.so that does not contain the *createEmptyDictFileNative* function exported for JNI.

Pull the library and verify that method exists:

```
adb pull /system/lib/libjni_latinime.so
nm -D libjni_latinime.so | grep createEmptyDictFile
```

If the library doesn't exist, you need to remount /system and install it.  If the native method doesn't exist, you need an updated libjni_latinime.so shared library